# List directories in a path recursively using only NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fs

I'm trying to make an elegant way to list all the directories and files inside them recursively. I want to list the files under each directories/sub-directories so that they are distinguishable. And the directory path must be provided by the user. My efforts are as below, the code is completely reproducible but I keep getting empty directories and the files are listed multiple times. What could be a better way to  accomplish the listing here?

```
//server.js
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
const rlp = require("readline");
const path = require("path");
const filesReadService = require("./filesReadService");
const handleFolders = require("./handleFolders");
//   var basePath = "C:\\Users\\My Computer\\Videos\\Captures";
const rl = rlp.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function directoryInput() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question("Please enter a valid directory: ", input => resolve(input));
  });
}

directoryInput().then(async userInput => {
  rl.close();
  let filesAndFolders = await handleFolders(userInput);
  await filesReadService(userInput, filesAndFolders);
});
```

...

```
//handleFolders.js
const fs = require("fs");

const handleFolders = (directory, isRecursive) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = handleFolders;
```

...

```
//filesReadService.js
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const handleFolders = require("./handleFolders");

const filesReadService = async (directoryPath, files) => {
  let fullPath;
  let obj = {};
  var promises = files.map(file => {
    fullPath = path.join(directoryPath, file);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.stat(fullPath, (err, stat) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        if (stat.isFile()) {
          obj = {
            file,
            isFile: true
          };
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          obj = {
            file,
            isFolder: true
          };
        }

        resolve(obj);
      });
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(
    values => {
      console.log("The files in this directory:");
      values
        .filter(value => value.isFile)
        .forEach(value => console.log(value.file));
      console.log("\nThe folders in this directory:");

      values
        .filter(value => value.isFolder === true)
        .forEach(async value => {
          let folderPath = path.join(directoryPath, value.file);
          let foldersAndFiles = await handleFolders(folderPath, true);
          console.log(value.file, ":\t", foldersAndFiles);
          await filesReadService(folderPath, foldersAndFiles);
        });
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
};

module.exports = filesReadService;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const fs = require("fs"), path = require("path");
function recursivelyListDir(dir, callback) {
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(f => {
    let dirPath = path.join(dir, f);
    let isDirectory = fs.statSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
    isDirectory
      ? recursivelyListDir(dirPath, callback)
      : callback(path.join(dir, f));
  });
}

// Function Usage.

recursivelyListDir(__dirname, function(filePath) {
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");
  console.log(filePath);
});
```

Comment: I need to use ES6 at least.

Comment: what ES6 features are you trying to use?

Comment: Higher order functions, arrow functions and all that
Besides, what is walkDir? The code throws an error saying: "walkDir is not defined"
Edit: never mind the "Credits" cleared it out, but it still throws an error: 
"return binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position); (^ points on read)
                 

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read"

Comment: you can accomodate the code shared to convert it to arrow functions.  Your original post doesn't emphasize on using it anyways.  I have fixed the typo and changed the function call so it uses current directory.  Put the file in the directory you want to list recursively and it will work.  I tested and it worked for me

Comment: Your code works, but using sync functions aren't very efficient imo, I used async functions for readdir, stat etc with promises by myself and made it to work. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Fair enough.  I am glad you were able to change to asynchronous flow. :)

Answer (score 1):

As of [Node 10.10.0](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback), `readdir()` and `readdirSync()` have a `withFileTypes` option that will cause it to return an array of `DirEnt`, which removes the need for the call to `statSync()`.

The example from @noor can be simplified to something like:

```
function readdirRecursiveSync(dir) {
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
    return dirs.reduce((acc, file) => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file.name);
        return acc.concat(
            file.isDirectory() ? readdirRecursiveSync(filePath) : filePath
        );
    }, []);
}
```

Or if you want to optionally include the directory:

```
function readdirRecursiveSync(dir, includeDirs) {
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true });
    return dirs.reduce((acc, file) => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file.name);
        return acc.concat(
            file.isDirectory() ? readdirRecursiveSync(filePath, includeDirs) : [],
            !file.isDirectory() || includeDirs ? filePath : []
        );
    }, []);
}
```